# select:hover inside grid-area with overflow: scroll causes Safari to jump to top

Tags: html, css, safari, pseudo-class

so I have this really weird problem I just can't wrap my head around. If you run the snippet in Safari, you can see that as soon as you hover the `select` field, the `.page` div scrolls to the top.

This only happens when `.page` is part of a grid and you have a `select:hover` rule. When you are just constraining the height without being in a grid, this doesn't happen.

Maybe someone can give me a hint as to why this is happening.

PS: In Chrome and Firefox this is working just fine.

```css
.site {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar header""sidebar page";
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr;
  height: 200px;
}

aside {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  color: transparent;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: transparent;
}

.page {
  grid-area: page;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.spacer {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

select:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">

  <aside>
    Sidebar
  </aside>
  
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  
  <main class="page">
    <div class="spacer">Scroll down...</div>
    <label for="test">Hover the select</label>
    <select name="test" id="test">
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
      <option value="2">Value 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="spacer">More content...</div>
  </main>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved it for now, so I hope I can help someone else with this.

#### Solution

When you set `max-height: 100%` on the `.page` div, everything works as expected. Compare the snippets in Safari to see it working.

```css
.site {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar header""sidebar page";
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr;
  height: 200px;
}

aside {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  color: transparent;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: transparent;
}

.page {
  grid-area: page;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.spacer {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

select:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">

  <aside>
    Sidebar
  </aside>
  
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  
  <main class="page">
    <div class="spacer">Scroll down...</div>
    <label for="test">Hover the select</label>
    <select name="test" id="test">
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
      <option value="2">Value 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="spacer">More content...</div>
  </main>
  
</div>
```

```css
.site {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar header""sidebar page";
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr;
  height: 200px;
}

aside {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  color: transparent;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: transparent;
}

.page {
  grid-area: page;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.spacer {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

select:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">

  <aside>
    Sidebar
  </aside>
  
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  
  <main class="page">
    <div class="spacer">Scroll down...</div>
    <label for="test">Hover the select</label>
    <select name="test" id="test">
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
      <option value="2">Value 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="spacer">More content...</div>
  </main>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this issue in future and finds the posted fix is not working for them, I recommend checking out this answer, which worked beautifully for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57787425/1162928

(In my case, the scroll to top was happening on any focus event — buttons, text inputs, etc…)